# "doomed to" + noun or infinitive?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, infinitives, gerund-vs-infinitive

I know the phrase "doomed to failure" exists.
I also found someone [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/en-to-be-doomed-to-verb.2310585/) who suggests that both, "doomed to failure" and "doomed to fail" can be used for a specific situation:

> "I'm doomed to failure" expresses a final state of outcome.
>
> "I'm doomed to fail" expresses an inevitable action.

Questions:

1. Would someone (a native speaker?) actually use "doomed to fail" instead of "doomed to failure"?
2. How can this be applied to other verbs (even if it doesn't make a lot of sense in the first place), e.g. "to live"/"life". Would it be "doomed to life" or "doomed to live"?

Comment: We would more naturally say "It's doomed to failure" / "It's bound to fail".

Comment: Re #1: ~247k results on Google Books alone: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22doomed+to+fail%22&tbm=bks

Comment: I also saw that "doomed to failure" is used more often, but I'm also especially interested in how this one common phrase can be applied to other verbs/nouns (real world situations: naming a metal song, getting a tattoo, i don't know...). What would you choose, given the "live"/"life" example above, and if it's the verb instead of the noun ("failure"), why so?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Would someone (a native speaker?) actually use "doomed to fail" instead of "doomed to failure"?

Yes.

> If the first effort failed, the following efforts were doomed to fail.
>   [Jack London, *Burning Daylight*, Chapter VIII](https://london.thefreelibrary.com/Burning-Daylight/1-8#Doomed+to+Fail)

as well as about 247,000 [results](http://google.com/search?q=%22doomed%20to%20fail%22&tbm=bks) on Google Books.

---

> 2. How can this be applied to other verbs

Here's an example sentence from [American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/doomed):

> *"With the benefit of hindsight, the fans felt that they knew all along that the Red Sox were doomed to lose" (Daniel L. Schachter[sic]).*

Comment: Those who fail to learn from history are doomed to repeat it. (Sounds better than "doomed to its repetition")

Comment: 'Tithonus was doomed to live forever' // 'doomed to forever roll a boulder uphill' // 'doomed to forever: make the same mistakes/be/be linked with/remain/depend/wander/...'.

Answer (score 1):

William Shakespeare was indisputably (I hope) a native speaker of English.

> Ghost: I am thy father's spirit,
> **Doomed** for a certain term **to walk the night**, --*Hamlet*, Act 1 Scene 5

So to answer your questions

> 1. Would someone (a native speaker?) actually use "doomed to fail" instead of "doomed to failure"?

Yes, I just gave you an example. And here's another one:
[*Doomed to Fail: The Incredibly Loud History of Doom, Sludge, and Post-Metal*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Doomed_to_Fail/tDVcxAEACAAJ?hl=en) by American author [J.J. Anselmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._J._Anselmi)

> 2. How can this be applied to other verbs (even if it doesn't make a lot of sense in the first place), e.g. "to live"/"life". Would it be "doomed to life" or "doomed to live"?

See example 1.